# Cypress Command log truncate

Tags: javascript, testing, integration-testing, cypress

Is it possible to truncate the Command Log for the assertion methods?

I have such test

```
cy.request('/').its('body').should('contain' 'somestring');
```

The body contains the whole page HTML as a string which results in massive pollution in the Command log in cypress which leads to memory issues. If I would like to do more assertions it will crash cypress.

How can truncate the assert log so it doesn't load the whole `body` in the assertion Command Log
[image]

I've tried saving the HTML string to file and reading it so I could make an assertion like on a normal page but currently, it seems not possible in Cypress to load the local file.

Cherrio is also a thing I could potentially use to retrieve data from that HTML string but I would like to avoid using it.

Comment: You can check out this plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-terminal-report. This provides options to truncate all type of logs on cypress (Eg. Command, cy.log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to suppressing the verbiage in the log is to pre-test the condition,

```
cy.request('http://example.com')
  .its('body')
  .then(body => body.includes('Example'))    // map to a boolean
  .should(result => expect(result, 'Body contains "Example"').to.be.true)
```

results in

```
assert    Body contains "Example": expected true to be true
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Arguments), you can pass `{ log: false }` to request.
Check the *options* section on above documentation

Comment: It doesn't work because the log is not from the request but from the assertion.